# Foreach aninhado com Blade no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Preciso exibir em um relatório três informações aninhadas e a ideia é exibir lançamentos de um balancete, este balancete pertence a um plano de contas e o plano de contas pertence a um grupo.

Portanto deve aparecer o seguinte na tela:

**Plano de conta 1**

> - Grupo 1
>
>   - lançamento 1
>   - lançamento 2
> - Grupo 2
>
>   - lançamento 1
>   - Plano de contas 2
> - Grupo 3
>
>   - lançamento 1
>   - lançamento 2

Estou usando `DBQuery` para obter os dados no `Backend`, fazendo join entre todas as tabelas, mas sempre da erro.

```
privatefunctionBalanceteLancamentosPeriodo($inicio,$fim,$condominio_id,$plano_conta_id,$grupo)
{
    return$this->balancete_lancamento
     ->join('balancetes','balancetes.id','=','balancete_lancamentos.balancete_id')
     ->join('condominios','balancetes.condominio_id','=','condominios.id')
     ->join('grupos','grupos.plano_de_conta_id','=','balancete_lancamentos.plano_contas_id')
     ->select('balancete_lancamentos.historico','balancete_lancamentos.valor','balancete_lancamentos.plano_contas_id')
     ->where('condominios.id',$condominio_id)
     ->whereBetween('data_lancamento',[$inicio,$fim])
     ->where('balancete_lancamentos.plano_contas_id',$plano_conta_id)
     ->where('grupos.id',$grupo)
     ->orderBy('data_lancamento','asc')
     ->get();
}
```

Estou tentando exibir os dados no front da seguinte forma:

```
@foreach($lancamentos as $key => $value)
    {{ $key }} <br>
    @foreach($value as $sub_key => $sub_value)
        {{ $sub_key }} <br>
        @foreach($sub_value as $a)
            {{ $a }}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Estou obtendo o erro: Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Quando retiro o último @foreach() obtenho o retorno do número do índice do array e da propriedade do array, como na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual erro que dá ?

Comment: Isso seria muito tranquilo se você utilizar o `Eloquent` em vez de `DB`, porque nas relações já vem as informações que dão certo para montagem da tela

Comment: adicionei o erro e mais informações. A ideia é que eu possa acessar o item que corresponde a "tipo", por exemplo.